# Github page background image be changed to none

Tags: html, css, github-pages

This is my Github repository: https://github.com/Yicheng-1218/OceanCrisis

I have a question is why the style in the header will automatic to be changed to none?

I have use the main.css to change header's background image to other images but it does not work.

index.html:

```
<div id="header">

            <!-- Inner -->
            <div class="inner">
                <header>
                    <h1><a href="index.html" id="logo">OceanCrisis</a></h1>
                    <hr>
                    <p>海洋危機</p>
                </header>
                <footer>
                    <a href="#main" class="button circled scrolly">閱讀</a>
                </footer>
            </div>

            <!-- Nav -->
            <nav id="nav">
                <ul>
                    <li style="white-space: nowrap;"><a href="index.html">首頁</a></li>
                    <li style="white-space: nowrap;"><a href="#banner" class="scrolly">公益活動</a></li>
                    <li style="white-space: nowrap;"><a href="#features" class="scrolly">生態危機</a></li>
                    <li style="white-space: nowrap;"><a href="#footer" class="scrolly">關於</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>

        </div>
```

This is github page showed:

```
<div id="header" bis_skin_checked="1" style="background-image: none;">

            <!-- Inner -->
            <div class="inner" bis_skin_checked="1">
                <header>
                    <h1><a href="index.html" id="logo" bis_skin_checked="1">OceanCrisis</a></h1>
                    <hr>
                    <p>海洋危機</p>
                </header>
                <footer>
                    <a href="#main" class="button circled scrolly" bis_skin_checked="1">閱讀</a>
                </footer>
            </div>

            <!-- Nav -->
            <nav id="nav">
                <ul>
                    <li style="white-space: nowrap;"><a href="index.html" bis_skin_checked="1">首頁</a></li>
                    <li style="white-space: nowrap;"><a href="#banner" class="scrolly" bis_skin_checked="1">公益活動</a></li>
                    <li style="white-space: nowrap;"><a href="#features" class="scrolly" bis_skin_checked="1">生態危機</a></li>
                    <li style="white-space: nowrap;"><a href="#footer" class="scrolly" bis_skin_checked="1">關於</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>

        </div>
```

main.css

```
/* Header */

#header {
    position: relative;
    background-image: url("../images/114645.jpg");
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center center;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 7.5em 0 2em 0;
    cursor: default;
}
```

Comment: Can you please add your code as text? https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question

Answer (score 0):

```
#header {
    position: relative;
    background-image: url("./static/images/114645.jpg");
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center center;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 7.5em 0 2em 0;
    cursor: default;
}
```

`or`

```
#header {
    position: relative;
    background-image: url("static/images/114645.jpg");
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center center;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 7.5em 0 2em 0;
    cursor: default;
}
```

your `directory structure`:-

```
project > static >
        |        |- > css > main.css
        |        |        |- other css file
        |        |- > images > 114645.jpg
        |                    |- etc. images
        |
        |- index.html
        |- etc. file
```

- if you want to access than use `./static/images/114645.jpg"` or `static/images/114645.jpg`